# Numbers that don't start with (p-1) in base p for any p

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Say that an integer $n$ is *$p$-leading* if its expansion in base $p$ starts with the digit $p-1$. My postdoc, Lifan Guan, asks: are there infinitely many positive integers $n$ that are not $p$-leading for any odd prime $p$? That is: is the set
$$S = \mathbb{N}\setminus \bigcup_{p\geq 3} \bigcup_{d\geq 1} [p^d - p^{d-1},p^d)$$
infinite?

[My estimation is this is interesting, doable and non-trivial. I also suspect it must have been studied before!]

Comment: Have you/ has he implemented tests? I'm counting 39422 such numbers in $\{0,99999\}$ if I did it correctly (with Sage). Also it doesn't seem to be in OEIS, which doesn't recognize '38,39,40,41,49,50,51,52,53,81'

Comment: Yes, I recall he got something like that in the same range. The set is most likely infinite (heuristics also suggest that).

Comment: Do heuristics say anything on expected lower/upper natural density?

Comment: I'd expect the lower natural density to be positive.

Comment: ... well, at least once you pass to an arithmetic progression modulo a slowly growing product of very small primes.

Comment: That's upper natural density, right? By lower and upper natural density of $A$ I mean liminf and limsup of $\frac1n\#(A\cap\{1,\dots,n\})$.

Comment: Why doesn't lower natural density work? Effects of very small primes?

Comment: I don't claim that, it's just that I don't understand "*once you pass to an arithmetic progression modulo a slowly growing product of very small primes*".

Comment: Well, let's say that I'm guessing that the lower natural density is positive once you take care of small-prime issues (if needed; I haven't thought about it enough to be sure).

Comment: As far as I see, the equation (or rather the inequality) is $\lceil \log_p(n)\rceil>\log_p(n)+\frac1{p\ln p}$: does it hold for all prime $p\ge 3$?

Comment: Other than that, I could comment that the problem is clearly related to an equidistribution question, but I don't want to influence the discussion too much.

Comment: @Seva Well, strictly speaking, the inequality should be $\lceil \log_p(n)\rceil > \log_p(n) - \frac{\log(1-1/p)}{\log p}$, but what you say is a sufficient condition. Since $\sum_p \frac{1}{p \log p}$ converges, it is reasonable to conjecture that the lower natural density will be positive.

Comment: ... but a simple argument involving adding upper densities does not work, since $\sum_p 1/p$ diverges.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove those $n$ such that $n+1$ is prime: given this, I found 35637 such numbers in $\{0,\dots,99999\}$ (the exact count has little interest, but just in case somebody also computes and compares).

Answer (score 7):

Following some discussion with Harald (offline)... It appears that the answer is YES, the set is indeed infinite.

First ingredient:
We take the idea of adding upper densities, but use logarithmic densities instead of natural densities (*logarithmic density* meaning one sums reciprocals to $x$, divides by $\log{x}$, and sends $x$ to infinity). A short computation bounds the upper logarithmic density of integers which start with $p-1$ in some base $p > C$ by $\sum_{p > C} \frac{1}{(p-1)\log{p}}$. Unfortunately, this sum is larger than $1$ when $C=2$, so this does not immediately imply a positive answer to the question. So we have to work harder.

2nd component: One shows that if $g_1,\dots,g_m \ge 2$ are integers with $1/\log{g_1}, \dots, 1/\log{g_m}$ being $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, then the fractional parts $\{\log_{g_1} n\}, \dots, \{\log_{g_m} n\}$ are distributed like independent uniform random variables on $[0,1)$, with respect again to logarithmic density. This uses a Weyl-type criterion; the key point is that if $\gamma \ne 0$, then $e^{2\pi i \gamma \log{n}} = n^{2\pi i \gamma}$ has logarithmic mean value $0$. (The condition that $\gamma \ne 0$ explains the linear independence condition required on the numbers $1/\log g_i$.)

Now $1/\log{3}$ and $1/\log{5}$ are easily seen to be $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly independent, and so one gets from the second component that the integers which do not begin with $2$ in base $3$, and do not begin with $4$ in base $5$, comprise a set with logarithmic density
$$ (1-\log_3(3/2)) (1-\log_5(4/5)) \approx 0.543.$$
Then one uses the first component with $C=5$. The sum of $\frac{1}{(p-1)\log{p}}$ for $p>5$ can be proved to be $< 0.53$ (say). It follows that the set in question is indeed infinite, with lower logarithmic density $> 1/100$.

If $\{1/\log{p}\}_{p\ge 3}$ is a linearly independent set (over $\mathbb{Q}$), modifying the above argument would show that the logarithmic density is exactly $\prod_{p \ge 3} (1-\log_p(p/(p-1))$. But I think this linear independence is open.

Comment: Doesn't the desired linear independence assumption follow from the fundamental theorem extended to $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}_{+}$?

Comment: Does it? That certainly gives the linear independence of the numbers $\log{p}$, but we want $1/\log{p}$.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after my comment. I proved years ago that the sum of the reciprocals of the first primes was never an integer, but I'm not sure it can help.